# Get substring before last occurrence of a word in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a string `/abc/xyz/def/xyz/1234/lmn/xyz/7890/uvw` in Linux.

I want to extract the substring before the last occurrence of the string `xyz` using shell script.

Example:

Input:

```
/abc/xyz/def/xyz/1234/lmn/xyz/7890/uvw
```

Output:

```
/abc/xyz/def/xyz/1234/lmn
```

I searched online and there are solutions with single character separator, but I couldn't figure out how to get it working with a string separator like `xyz`.

Comment: According to you description, the substring should end in `lmn/`, including the last forward slash, but the example doesn't contain it. Which one is it?

Comment: @benjaminW thanks for your time. I am looking for substring without slash.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about this:

```
$ x=/abc/xyz/def/xyz/1234/lmn/xyz/7890/uvw
```

```
$ echo ${x%xyz*}
```

> ```
> /abc/xyz/def/xyz/1234/lmn/
> ```

```
$ echo ${x%/xyz*}
```

> ```
> /abc/xyz/def/xyz/1234/lmn
> ```

If you really don't want the `/` before the last `xyz`, then the second echo should be what you're looking for; if leaving the trailing `/` is acceptable, the first does that.

Comment: thanks for your help. This worked. I needed substring without slash, but having both solutions is itself bonus.
will be helpful if you can explain a little bit about solution.

Comment: It's just simple `bash` variable manipulation - `%` means "remove substring from right", and what follows it is a glob pattern for the substring you want to remove. I would highly recommend reading through the `bash` manual page at least once.

Comment: got it. % and # operators is what I should be looking for substring requirements.thanks